# Getting Server response: UNAVAILABLE even after following the steps of "QUICK START kotlin gRPC on android"

Tags: server, client, grpc, grpc-kotlin

I have followed all the steps given in [gRPC Kotlin QUICK START](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/kotlin/quickstart/),  I built and ran the server successfully and installed the Android app (Connected with adb over TCP in local network, same subnet, PC firewall is off). I ran the server using this command and got the expected output.
$ ./server/build/install/server/bin/hello-world-server
Server started, listening on 50051

But I am still getting an error when I click on the "Send gRPC Request" button, which says - "Server Response: UNAVAILABLE".

I have followed the steps given in the website as it is and still getting an error. When I type "Alice" in the message box according to the website, I have to get "Hello Alice". But that is not happening in my case.
Is there anything else I have to do for this to work which is not mentioned in the website?

Thank you!

Comment: I've not used Kotlin. The GitHub examples appear to be slightly more detailed than the gRPC page. See [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/tree/master/examples) page and expand "Android example" at the bottom of the page. For both alternatives, it seems you need `./gradlew :android:installDebug -PserverUrl={something}` and to update `gradle.properties` with `serverUrl={something}`

Comment: Thank you for your response.
It is working when I put the IP address of my PC. 
I have connected to an ADB and the program is not working when I enter the IP address of the connected ADB. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I had some port number issues. I just changed the port number and it worked.